# jQuery .onload Function to Remove Scrollbar Until Page Load Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow, onload

I want a jQuery function that removes the vertical scrollbar until the page has fully loaded but it doesn't seem to be working. Any insight on the problem would be great. Thanks!

```
$(window).on('load', function () {    
    $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');   
    $('body').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
});
```

```css
.stop-scrolling {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that your JS doesn't run until *after* the page has finished loading. This means the scroll bar is visible the entire time the page is loading. Then, once the page loads, you add the stop scrolling class and then, milliseconds later, you remove it again. The net result of this is that nothing appears to happen.

To achieve what you need, put the `.stop-scrolling` class directly in the HTML source of your page on the `<body>` element and then *only* remove it in the `window.load` event handler.

Comment: Thanks it is working now! Can't believe I missed this.